# Definition of "the same"

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Given a subgroup H of a group G such that $g^{-1}hg \in H$ for all $g \in G$ and all $h \in H$, I need to show that every left coset gH is the same as the right coset Hg.
In the context of this problem, what does "the same" mean?

Comment: You need to show that they are the same set.

Answer (score 3):

Cosets are sets themselves, so "the same" refers to set equality. Two sets are equal iff they have the same elements.